# Passing HTML attributes from a DeepReadonly object in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This works well

```
type Props =  DR<IBtnWrapperPropsBasic> & {otherbuttonProps?: ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>}

class Btn extends Component<Props, {}> {

    ...

    public render() {
        const {handleClick, stl, otherbuttonProps, ...otherProps} = this.props
        return (
            <button
                type="button"
                // @ts-ignore
                className={css(getNewDeepMutable([style, stl]))}
                onMouseDown={this.handleClickW}
                onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
                {...otherbuttonProps}
                {...otherProps}
            />
        )
    }
```

When I type `otherbuttonProps` as `DeepReadonly` I get an error, since `ButtonHtmlAttributes` expects regular array not a `ReadonelyArray`. I try to solve this by getting a `DeepMutable` copy of `otherbuttonProps`. But it fails and provides the following error:

[image]

It seems to me that the current versions of `DeepReadonly and DeepMutable fail handeling the`ButtonHTMLAttributes` type. 
Any suggestions?

Here are my implementations of DeepReadonly and DeepMutable:

```
type DeepReadonly<T> =
// tslint:disable-next-line: ban-types
    T extends  AnyFunction | Primitive ? T :
    T extends ReadonlyArray<infer R> ? IDRArray<R> :
    T extends ReadonlyMap<infer K, infer V> ? IDRMap<K, V> :
    T extends ReadonlySet<infer ItemType>? ReadonlySetDeep<ItemType>:
    T extends object ? DRObject<T> :
    T

interface IDRArray<T> extends ReadonlyArray<DeepReadonly<T>> {}

type DRObject<T> = {
    readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[P]>;
}

interface IDRMap<K, V> extends ReadonlyMap<DeepReadonly<K>, DeepReadonly<V>> {}

interface ReadonlySetDeep<ItemType>
    extends ReadonlySet<DeepReadonly<ItemType>> {}

export type DeepMutable<T> =
    // tslint:disable-next-line: ban-types
        T extends  AnyFunction | Primitive ? T :
        T extends ReadonlyArray<infer R> ? IDeepMuttableArray<R> :
        T extends ReadonlyMap<infer K, infer V> ? IDeepMutableMap<K, V> :
        T extends ReadonlySet<infer ItemType>? DeepMutableSetDeep<ItemType>:
        T extends object ? DeepMutableObject<T> :
        T

interface IDeepMuttableArray<T> extends Array<DeepMutable<T>> {}

type DeepMutableObject<T> = {
    readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepMutable<T[P]>;
}

interface IDeepMutableMap<K, V> extends Map<DeepMutable<K>, DeepMutable<V>> {}

interface DeepMutableSetDeep<ItemType>
    extends Set<DeepMutable<ItemType>> {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `IDRArray` and `IDeepMuttableArray` you can just use  `DRObject` and `DeepMutableObject` for arrays as well (at least since 3.1 I think). This will make your types round-trip better through `DeepMutable<DeepReadonly<T>>`:

```
type o = DeepMutable<DeepReadonly<{
    p: string[]
}>> // { p: string[] }
```

Except for this observation, your code works, the only error I find is that mutable does not actually remove `readonly`, it should be:

```
type DeepMutableObject<T> = {
    -readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepMutable<T[P]>;
}
```

Full Code:

```
type AnyFunction =(...a: any[]) => any
type Primitive = number | string | void | undefined | boolean | null;
type DeepReadonly<T> =
// tslint:disable-next-line: ban-types
    T extends  AnyFunction | Primitive ? T :
    T extends ReadonlyArray<infer R> ? DRObject<T> :
    T extends ReadonlyMap<infer K, infer V> ? IDRMap<K, V> :
    T extends ReadonlySet<infer ItemType>? ReadonlySetDeep<ItemType>:
    T extends object ? DRObject<T> :
    T

type DRObject<T> = {
    readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[P]>;
}

interface IDRMap<K, V> extends ReadonlyMap<DeepReadonly<K>, DeepReadonly<V>> {}

interface ReadonlySetDeep<ItemType>
    extends ReadonlySet<DeepReadonly<ItemType>> {}

export type DeepMutable<T> =
    // tslint:disable-next-line: ban-types
        T extends  AnyFunction | Primitive ? T :
        T extends ReadonlyArray<infer R> ? DeepMutableObject<T> :
        T extends ReadonlyMap<infer K, infer V> ? IDeepMutableMap<K, V> :
        T extends ReadonlySet<infer ItemType>? DeepMutableSetDeep<ItemType>:
        T extends object ? DeepMutableObject<T> :
        T

type DeepMutableObject<T> = {
    -readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepMutable<T[P]>;
}

interface IDeepMutableMap<K, V> extends Map<DeepMutable<K>, DeepMutable<V>> {}

interface DeepMutableSetDeep<ItemType>
    extends Set<DeepMutable<ItemType>> {}

type DR<T> = DeepReadonly<T>
type IBtnWrapperPropsBasic = {
}
type Props =  DR<IBtnWrapperPropsBasic> & {otherbuttonProps?: DR<React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>>}

class Btn extends Component<Props, {}> {
    handleClickW: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void;
    handleKeyDown: (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;

    public render() {
        const { otherbuttonProps, ...otherProps} = this.props;
        return (
            <button
                type="button"
                onMouseDown={this.handleClickW}
                onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
                {...mutable(otherbuttonProps)}
                {...otherProps}
            />
        )
    }
}

function mutable<T>(p: T) : DeepMutable<T>  {
    return p as any;
}
```